# GCE - different username if i use SSH or log in from terminal?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a new project with nothing in it.

When I created my first micro instance I did the following

1. Connect to it using the browser window SSH.
   I see:

   **user_name@instance-1:~$**
2. If I connect using the gcloud command:

   gcloud compute --project "projectname-165421" ssh --zone "us-east1-b" "instance-1"

   I am brought to:

   **username@instance-1:~$**

Why is this happening, and how do I resolve it?

This is creating two separate users which is creating a great deal of confusion for me!

Thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, the cloudSDK will try to connect using the user running the command.

If you look at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh), 
It says you can specify the username like you would, with your default ssh client.

Meaning on your computer:

```
gcloud compute --project "projectname-165421" ssh --zone "us-east1-b" "user_name@instance-1"
```

Alternatively, switch user in the browser window SSH:

```
sudo su username
```

Comment: Any way to set the default user `gcloud` connects with?

Comment: @AntonTarasenko I was looking for an answer to this same question. I thought that setting my account in my gcloud config would do this for me. Unfortunately, I still need to set my user_name@instance when connecting.

Answer (score 5):

I use this command to fix it on MacOS:

```
LOGNAME=ubuntu gcloud compute ssh app1
```

Answer (score 2):

In answer to some of the comments: **yes**, you can change the default username. This is stored under the environment variable $USER. You can view the current value of this variable by running in your local terminal:

```
echo $USER
```

You can set the value of this variable to the default user you would like, by running the following (assuming you are using any of bash/zsh):

```
export USER=the_new_default_user
```

For example, if the new desired default user is "pablo" then:

```
export USER=pablo
```

Now, every time you run the following command to ssh in your instance, you'll ssh into pablo:

```
gcloud compute ssh MY_INSTANCE
```

I hope this helps!