# GCP VM Instance - OS Login as another user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to connect to a VM as another user through the command line on my local computer, however it doesn't seem to work.
I remember doing this before with the same command:

```
gcloud compute --project MYPROJECT ssh usernameA@vminstance --zone "myzone"
```

I am getting a warning and then get connected as myself not usernameA

```
WARNING: Using OS Login user [usernameB] instead of default user [usernameA]
```

According to GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#USER), this should work but I can't recall if I need to change any of the config settings

EDIT:
 I have generated a key and added it to the VM Instance ssh keys and still get the same warning.

Comment: What have you done on the instance to enable usernameA@vminstance logins via SSH? Have you installed the SSH keys for this user? Edit your question with these details.

Answer (score 2):

You can get more details using the flag `--verbosity=debug` when using the command:

`gcloud compute --project MYPROJECT ssh usernameA@vminstance --zone "myzone"`

Verify, if there are keys present under the user's home directory.

On Linux/Unix based systems: 
`cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

On Windows system with Google Cloud SDK installed: 
`Path: C:\Users\user-name\.ssh`

Moreover, are you able to login with other users ex: `"usernameC"` to the VM instance?

Something similar could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565660/gce-different-username-if-i-use-ssh-or-log-in-from-terminal).

[Connecting to Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) and [Connecting to Instances Using Advanced Methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced) could also help.

Answer (score 1):

What solved a similar issue for me was adding a user flag to the end of the typical Google Cloud SSH command, i.e.

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone <instance_zone> <instance_name> --project <project_name> -- -l <other_user_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just the instance name on the command:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh <instance_name> --zone <instance_zone>
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! this does not resolve my issue, as I need to log in as a different user and the command you propose will log me in as the default user

Comment: ok from the VM try issuing `ssh-keygen` then try again connecting again with the user you are using: `gcloud compute --project MYPROJECT ssh usernameA@vminstance --zone "myzone"`

Comment: I ended up signing in as the other user and connecting through SSH (I did not see your answer on time) but will try on a separate VM/PC so that we can close the question

Comment: Ok, i generated a new key for the user and added it to the ssh keys of the instance, still get the same warning :/

Comment: @Jhon is right have you install the SSH key for that user? ( not specified from my last reply ), btw you can also login using the default command and then switch the user ( not the best practice ). furthermore could you create new user and try doing into the same VM. sorry for my delay reply.